# Java/Derby - Should I manage the application memory myself?

Tags: java, memory, jdbc, out-of-memory, derby

I wrote this simple class in NetBeans, in order to learn about connecting to and managing a Derby database through Java code, and am using the sample database provided by the IDE as the connection target. I believe it's a rather straightforward database connection example:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Some code that allows me to start the connection only after keyboard input
        System.out.println("Program will now connect to database");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Redirecting DriverManager's output to the console's standard output
        DriverManager.setLogWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));

        // This is where I connect to the database, execute a query and print a result
        // Still barebones, I am learning SQL basics yet
        String dbURL ="jdbc:derby:C:\\users\\project2100\\.netbeans-derby\\sample";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "app", "app")) {
            System.out.println("Connected");

            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet output = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
                while (output.next()) {
                    System.out.println(output.getString("NAME"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // Recently added to keep the application alive
        // This way, I can monitor memory usage on Task Manager
        try {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Java's standard output gives me the results I expect, but `DriverManager`'s output tells me something I'm worrying about; here's the full console output from an application run:

```
run:
Program will now connect to database

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\users\project2100\.netbeans-derby\sample")
    trying org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40
SQLState(08004) vendor code(40000)
java.sql.SQLException: Connection refused : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javadbpg.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:35)
SQLState(08004) vendor code(40000)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection refused : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver20.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javadbpg.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:35)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection refused : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
getConnection returning org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver40
Connected
Jumbo Eagle Corp
New Enterprises
Wren Computers
Small Bill Company
Bob Hosting Corp.
Early CentralComp
John Valley Computers
Big Network Systems
West Valley Inc.
Zed Motor Co
Big Car Parts
Old Media Productions
Yankee Computer Repair Ltd

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)
```

NOTE: There is a 1-2 seconds hang between the first two errors.

Just recently, after looking around the Internet for what might be causing these `OutOfMemoryError`s, I added that last `try` block and observed the application's memory footprint. It goes from an initial ~9MB to ~40MB.

Therefore, should I set some memory parameters inside the application, in order to reduce these errors, and eventually gain performance? (If so, could I have some pointers?) Or should i just leave everything as is and let `DriverManager` work by itself?

**2014-08-07 Follow-up:**

This time, I ran the application on debug mode, and wrote down the private memory usage step by step. Points of interest are as follows:

- Memory amount *right before* the `try (Connection conn = ...` statement is 12MB;
- Following this, the program hangs for about 5 seconds and fires all the `OutOfMemoryErrors` described above;
- After the 5 seconds have elapsed, the program reserves a total memory of 37MB *right before* the `System.out.println("Connected");` statement;
- The `executeQuery` statement adds up another 7MB, total: 45MB. Execution time is negligible (<1/2sec);

Here's the `derby.log` file as requested by Bryan Pendleton, its state is after all the previous tests:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Thu Aug 07 10:10:11 CEST 2014:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.10.1.3 - (1557168): instance a816c00e-0147-af84-a381-0000263f2b92 
on database directory C:\Users\Project2100\.netbeans-derby\C3Subjects with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@58644d46 
Loaded from file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/db/lib/derby.jar
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_05-b13
user.dir=C:\Users\Project2100\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaDB Proving Grounds
os.name=Windows 7
os.arch=amd64
os.version=6.1
derby.system.home=C:\users\Project2100\.netbeans-derby
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

Yesterday, I kept searching on the Internet about memory management, and attempted to use the CLI arguments `-Xms` and `-Xns` to raise the application's starting memory, to no avail; these options manipulate only the application's reserved memory, and leaves the actual memory initially used at the usual 9-10MB. I'm getting the same memory values, errors and hangs anyway.

I guess that, for now, I'm going to chalk this behavior under `loading database...` and go on with SQL itself, since the system console doesn't list any complaints at all. However, if there is indeed a way to preemptively allocate more memory on database connection, I'd be grateful to get an answer about it.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: `try(ResultSet output = ...´ too. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/ - search "derby.storage"

Comment: I would ensure the process has at least 1 GB or more.  Trying to save a few MB is likely to be unproductive.

Comment: This is quite strange. I don't understand what's happening. I don't think I've ever tried snooping on DriverManager's output like that before. Since you're getting the right output from your query, clearly you are successfully establishing a connection and operating Derby. What does your derby.log look like? Are you running in a configuration where 40 MB actually represents an out-of-memory situation?

Comment: @JoopEggen - I'm afraid those storage properties refer to storage memory, whereas what concerns me is primary memory usage, correct me if I'm wrong... though that solved some of my difficulties in database URL resolving :)

@PeterLawrey I'd like to know how, -Xms and -Xns don't do the trick

@Bryan Pendleton Yeah, if I didn't redirect `DriverManager`'s output stream, I would still be totally oblivious to why my application hangs for 5 seconds on connection. The databases I'm using now isn't imposing, but I intend to make a video scheduling software; I expect the resulting DB to be huge.

Comment: Agh, I'm very sorry for the bad formatting, seems SO doesn't like line breaks.

Comment: Just to report: I'm getting exactly the same problem. It reports OutOfMemory error during database connection, with an ugly stack trace, but the connection actually succeeds and I can use the database successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is a static variable in the org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection:

```
/**
 * Static exception to be thrown when a Connection request can not
 * be fulfilled due to lack of memory. A static exception as the lack
 * of memory would most likely cause another OutOfMemoryException and
 * if there is not enough memory to create the OOME exception then something
 * like the VM dying could occur. Simpler just to throw a static.
 */
public static final SQLException NO_MEM =
    newSQLException(SQLState.LOGIN_FAILED, "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError");
```

When you set up the logwriter for DriverManager, the SQLException will be printed:

```
public SQLException(String reason, String SQLState, int vendorCode) {
    super(reason);
    this.SQLState = SQLState;
    this.vendorCode = vendorCode;
    if (!(this instanceof SQLWarning)) {
        if (DriverManager.getLogWriter() != null) {
            DriverManager.println("SQLState(" + SQLState +
                                            ") vendor code(" + vendorCode + ")");
            printStackTrace(DriverManager.getLogWriter());
        }
    }
}
```

That's why we have an ugly stack trace.